# Which 3 size/resolution images to upload in image set to support all devices?

Tags: ios, xcode, assets

Image assets are now preferred over resources in IOS, which supports to upload only 3 versions of the image. 1x, 2x & 3x.

But there are number of device resolutions to support on iPhones

> 640x1136  - 5 series 
>   750x1334  - 6, 6s, 7, 8 
>   1242x2208 - (6, 6s, 7, 8) plus 
>   1125x2436 - X, XS 
>   828x1792  - XR 
>   1242x2688 - XS Max

I can understand what 1x, 2x & 3x resolutions are, eg. 320px(1x), 640px(2x) & 960(3x).

But I can not understand which 3 image sizes to upload to support all devices, so that complete image appear full screen on all devices?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The resolutions are 1x, 2x and 3x. In most cases you should scale sizes of images so that for instance 1x is `100x100`, 2x is `200x200` and 3x is `300x300`.

This has nothing to do with resolution but rather the DPI scale. It is a value you get from `UIScreen.main.scale`. What this is is the scale between your coordinate system and scree pixel coordinate system. For instance if you take a 2x device with resolution of `750x1334` and print out frame you would get `375x667` by checking `UIApplication.shared.keyWindow!.frame`.

That means that if you place an image view with frame size `100x100` on a 2x device it will take `200x200` pixels. For 3x it will take `300x300` pixels. So that is why the 2x and 3x images should be larger.

The problem occurs if you want to scale image directly depending on screen size. Assume the following:

`let imageWidth: CGFloat = 44.0/375.0*view.frame.size.width`

If this is used for image size then your image will proportionally resize depending on your screen size. And doing this you would need a better system for icons than having 3 versions of it. You could put them into assets and have 3 images per screen resolution.

But in most cases it is better to keep the image size and increase the whitespace around it. So assume a screen with width of 375 would have an image of width 100 in the middle. It would produce 137,5 whitespace on each of the sides. Now seeing the same scene on device with width of 414 would produce 157 whitespace on which of the sides. This is usually acceptable.

If you really need to scale images you should also consider scaling fonts. If one of your icons increases in size by 10% then most likely a text next to it should have increased font size by 10%. This may later greatly complicate things due to rounding of font sizes to integer value. So I suggest you avoid this.

Comment: Thank you for taking time & explaining in detail! As I mentioned I can understand about 1x, 2x resolutions/dpis. I know that if size is 414x896, 2x vesion is  828x1792 and 3x is 1242x2688. But there are so many sizes to support. I have a plain image without text, so what sizes I can upload in those 3 boxes so it displayed same on all devices without cutting edges, that is my question.

Comment: @MukeshModhvadiya as said, it depends. If you are using something like an icon then you should target having those sizes multiplied by 2 or by 3 relative to 1x scale. But if you have something like background and you want to have the resolution pixel perfect then you need 3 images for each of the resolutions you support. Naturally it is better having just 1 image that can be fitted into all screens; you can use a setting for content mode to be scaleAspectFill to fill the whole background without distorting the image. Or scaleAspectFit if you need to see the whole image...